# After quitting job, can a blue card holder Leave Germany, return to wrap up things and travel out of the EU

Tags: germany, blue-card, foreign-employment, overstay

I hold a blue card and employed from 10 months in Germany.

I understand my blue card will be valid for 3 months after I quit my job. I want to quit my job and visit my home country for a month and a half and return to Germany. I have an offer from a foreign Employer and I have no intentions to stay in Germany after I return.

1. Is travel out of Germany allowed between jobs with a Blue Card?
2. Will I have to inform the authorities of my job status before I travel to my home country, and will it cause any problems in my travel?

My plan is to be back in Germany, de-register here and wrap up things. Then travel from Germany to my new employer out of the EU.

Comment: In other words, after your return you will be moving to another country to start working? Will you be maintaining your present residence in Germany until you move to that country?

Comment: Yes I plan to deregister here once I'm back from my vacation and wrap up things and leave to the foreign country out of EU. So looking at maintaining residence until my return form home country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement to inform the immigration office that you are, either for a short time or permanently, leaving the country.

It is only when they *think* that you have permanently left (such as after deregisteration and leaving the country) that the residence permit, through their action, could expire earlier than otherwise stated on the card.

> [§ 51 (1) AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050)
> **The residence title expires in the following cases**
> ...
> **6.** if the foreigner leaves the federal territory for a reason which **is not temporary in nature**,
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Section 51 - Termination of lawful residence; continued validity of restrictions](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050)

Comment: Ok then I can as well de register and carry on! Thank you